# Catching EndpointNotFoundException in BT 2020 Orchestration

Tags: exception, biztalk

It seems catching System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException doesn't work in orchestrations despite of:

- port settings: Delivery Notification = Transmitted (it should work without this in two-way port)
- catching exception in specific order
- catching Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.DeliveryFailureException
- catching super class exception CommunicationObjectFaultedException like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74de3cbc-fd9c-4f99-a50d-7ff9f9b260d6/delivery-notification-for-two-way-ports?forum=biztalkgeneral)
- scope in scope configuration like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74de3cbc-fd9c-4f99-a50d-7ff9f9b260d6/delivery-notification-for-two-way-ports?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Orchestration only catches System.Exception. Is that bug or am I missing something?

EDIT :
My configuration:

- Sendport WCF-WebHttp
- Endpoint REST

I managed to put Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.XlangSoapException catch type by editing odx file in notepad (its hack!)- and This actually works as I want becasue
this type encapsulates System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException by Biztalk I persume.

This type of exception is thrown in orchesration but VS doesnt let me choose this type of exception I believe that is done in purpose to not to do that.

[image: my orchestraton]

Comment: Note: Even if you put the Exception catch blocks in a certain order, if the build determines that you have a more specific one after a more generic, it will re-order them and emit a warning that it has done so.  Also can you add your configuration in the question, rather than linking to posts on other forums (especially as that forum might be decommissioned)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I've added my configuration